# how can i integrate redux store to react native?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I have created basic ui with **react native** and Navigation React **Navigation V2**
 My App's entry file(App.js) like this

//App.js

```
const App = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    StartupScreen: Validator, //validating accesstoken existing or not if existing navigate to Dashboard otherwise login page 
    Login:Login, 
    DashBoard: Dashboard //tabbed view
  },  
  {
    initialRouteName: 'StartupScreen',
  }
);

export default App
```

how can integrate here with redux?

that is how can I pass store to app like

```
<Provider store={store}> <App /></Provider>
```

to get store every page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Active reading: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

So you need to return the Provider wrapping your navigator.

// App.js

```
const App = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    StartupScreen: Validator,
    Login:Login, 
    DashBoard: Dashboard
  },  
  {
    initialRouteName: 'StartupScreen',
  }
);

export default function() {
  return <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>;
}
```

Do not forget to import the Provider and to create the store using reducers and etc.

Comment: thank you for the reply,  this way i can't wrap the App. <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider> will get error message.I have already imported neccessory library/plugins

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented Redux in My template. You can refer this https://github.com/vishaljadav24/react-native-base-template