# how to use Redux with createSwitchNavigator?

Tags: react-native, redux, navigation, state-management

I am trying to use switch navigator with redux. following is my code.

```
import { createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import EmployeeListScreen from '../screens/EmployeeListScreen';
import DetailsView from '../screens/EmployeeDetailViewScreen';
import EmployeeForm from '../screens/EmployeeForm';
import AuthLoadingScreen from "../screens/AuthLoadingScreen.js";
import {connect  } from "react-redux";
import { AppNavigator } from "../navigations/AppNavigator.js";

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ 
    List:{screen:EmployeeListScreen},
    Detail:{screen:DetailsView},
    Form:{screen:EmployeeForm}
 });
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ Login: LoginScreen });

export const AuthNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppNavigator,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
);

const AuthWithNavigationState = ({ dispatch, nav }) => (
    <AuthNavigator  />
  );

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    nav: state.nav,
  });

  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthWithNavigationState);
```

I'm importing this component is my App.js file and using it as follows to connect with redux store but it is giving me error like, React is not defined and error is located at connect(AuthWithNavigationState)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore,applyMiddleware  } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import AppReducer from './src/reducers/AppReducer';
import AuthWithNavigationState from './src/navigations/AuthNavigator.js';

const store = createStore(AppReducer,applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AuthWithNavigationState/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried to follow instruction from below link but still I am getting the same error.

[how can i integrate redux store to react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601353/how-can-i-integrate-redux-store-to-react-native)

**Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after too much trying, I figure out that, The switch navigator don't need to be connect to the store, so below step was incorrect.

```
const AuthWithNavigationState = ({ dispatch, nav }) => (
    <AuthNavigator  />
  );

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    nav: state.nav,
  });

  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthWithNavigationState);
```

I simply exported AuthNavigator and imported in App.js and this worked for me.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore,applyMiddleware  } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import AppReducer from './src/reducers/AppReducer';
import AuthNavigatorfrom './src/navigations/AuthNavigator.js';

const store = createStore(AppReducer,applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AuthNavigator/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```